# Dictionary ObjectIdentifier: CustomClass Questions about Dictionary append in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi? I have created **BananaMilkFactory**, **CiderFactory** and **CantataCoffeeFactory** that inherit superclass called **Beverage**. And I made an **Inventory** that bundles Beverages into an array.

For example, if you create 3 Banana Milk, 2 Cider, 1 Cantata Coffee, Inventory will have a total of 6 Beverages.

The function I want is **[ObjectIdentifier: Inventory]** and I want to return the Beverages of the same ObjectIdentifier separately.

```swift
// [BananaMilk(), BananaMilk(), BananaMilk(), Cider(), Cider(), CantataCoffee()]
private var inventory: [Beverage]

func readInventores() -> [ObjectIdentifier : Inventory] {
    var allInventores = [ObjectIdentifier : Inventory]()

    self.inventory.forEach { beverage in
        // Help~!!
    }
            
    return allInventores
}
```

What should I do to return it in [ObejctIdentifier: Inventory] format?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Inventory` and `Beverage`?

Comment: I made [Beverage] as Inventory type.

Comment: Now I am confused. What do you expect `readInventores` to return? I'm assuming you want to group the beverages by their type? What are the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: If I get it right Inventory is defined somehow as an array of beverages but since ObjectIdentifier is unique for each instance the dictionary you want would only contain _one_ Beverage object per key so the dictionary is actually pointless and you might as well return an Inventory (or a dictionary [ObjectIdentifier:Beverage]). My guess is that you have misunderstood what ObjectIdentifier is.

Comment: Please, Caleb, reconstruct and post your **expected output**, that would be a bery good starting point

Answer (score -2):

create an array which contains class name of object (BananaMilkFactory, CiderFactory ....). Iterate through the array,put objects with the same class name in a new array.I don't know if I understand your question correctly.